# How to transfer data from a column to multiple columns using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I use python to transfer data from the "weekday" column and multiple columns (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...) and vice versa

```
       buyer    weekday    
0      A        Saturday
1      A        Friday
2      B        Monday
3      B        Tuesday
4      B        Thursday
5      C        Monday
```

Desired Outcome:

```
       buyer   Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
0      A                                           Y       Y       
1      B         Y       Y                 Y                            
2      C         Y
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'buyer': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'weekday': ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Monday']})
w_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df = pd.crosstab(df['buyer'], df['weekday']).replace({0: '', 1: 'Y'})
df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(set(w_days).difference(df.columns), ''))[w_days].reset_index().rename_axis(columns={'weekday': ''})
print(df)
```

```
  buyer Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
0     A                                        Y        Y       
1     B      Y       Y                  Y                       
2     C      Y
```

Comment: Good way of handling missing values/weekdays. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**

Introduce a dummy column for values and use [pivot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```py
import calendar
weekdays = list(calendar.day_name)

df = pd.DataFrame({'buyer': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'weekday': ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Monday']})

df["dummy"] = "Y"

df = df.pivot(index="buyer", columns="weekday", values="dummy").reindex(labels=weekdays, axis=1).fillna("").reset_index().rename_axis(columns={"weekday": ""})

[Out]:
  buyer Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
0     A                                        Y        Y       
1     B      Y       Y                  Y                       
2     C      Y
```

**Option #2**

Use a combination of `groupby`, `size` & `unstack` and  finally `replace` values:

```py
import calendar
weekdays = list(calendar.day_name)

df = pd.DataFrame({'buyer': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'weekday': ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Monday']})

df = df = df.groupby(["buyer", "weekday"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).replace({1:"Y",0:""}).reindex(labels=weekdays, axis=1).fillna("").reset_index().rename_axis(columns={"weekday": ""})

[Out]:
  buyer Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
0     A                                        Y        Y       
1     B      Y       Y                  Y                       
2     C      Y
```